# Why is a matrix multiplied by an eigenvector not parallel to that eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenfunctions

If $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigenvalue with a corresponding eigenvector $v$, then $A v$ is parallel to $v$.

This statement is false. Why is that? Would it be parallel to $\lambda v$?

Comment: What is your definition of parallel?

Comment: What are your definitions of eigenvector and eigenvalue?

Comment: If $\vec{v}\in S_\lambda$ $A\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}=\lambda||\vec{v}||^2=1 \iff ||\vec{v}||^2=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$

Comment: What makes you think the statement is false, Samurai? Can you show us a counterexample?

Comment: The only explantions that I can come up with are: (1) it's a calculation mistake, (2) perhaps $\lambda=0$ and in someone's definition, two vectors are said to be parallel only if they are scalar multiples of *each other* (this is just a wild guess; personally, I treat $0$ as a vector that is parallel to every vector).

Comment: Any thoughts, Samurai? Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what to make of your question as you didn't specify what matrix $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of. 
If $A$ were the matrix corresponding to that eigenvector, then $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$, by definition, meaning the statement would be *true*. Since you're sure the statement is false, then we can assume that $A$ is not the matrix corresponding to that eigenvector. In that case, of course, $A\vec{v}$ need not equal $\lambda \vec{v}$.
If you're confused about what it means to be parallel or what an Eigenvector is, I recommend [3b1b's video on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g).